# "error: failed to run custom build command for `libp2p-core v0.37.0`" in windows

Tags: substrate-node-template

I just started experimenting with substrate and I'm getting this error when running `cargo build --release`:

> Compiling semver v1.0.14 error: failed to run custom build command
> for `libp2p-core v0.37.0`
>
> Caused by:   process didn't exit successfully:
> `C:\blockchain\substrate\target\release\build\libp2p-core-b022c239b3d22274\build-script-build`
> (exit code: 101)   --- stdout   Running: "C:\protoc-21.9-win64\bin"
> "--include_imports" "--include_source_info" "-o"
> "C:\Users\luish\AppData\Local\Temp\prost-buildu5HDyP\prost-descriptor-set"
> "-I" "src" "src/keys.proto" "src/envelope.proto"
> "src/peer_record.proto"
>
> --- stderr   thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on
> an `Err` value: Custom { kind: PermissionDenied, error: "failed to
> invoke protoc (hint: https://docs.rs/prost-build/#sourcing-protoc):
> (path: "C:\\protoc-21.9-win64\\bin"): Access is denied. (os
> error 5)" }',
> C:\Users\luish.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\libp2p-core-0.37.0\build.rs:30:6
> note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a
> backtrace

Comment: Looks like you got a permission/access denied. Check the privileges of the file/user/group.

Comment: Also, it is recommended that you use WSL: https://docs.substrate.io/install/windows

Comment: Tryed this again in WSL and it worked fine ! Thank you

Comment: Curious, did you use WSL or WSL2?